# How to use new and delete in this scenario

Tags: c++, pointers, hash, binary-search-tree

So I have a class `aCollection` that has as its members a binary search tree and a hash table (for organizing data by different parameters). The way I designed the program to work was that `aCollection` has an `add(aVendor& vendor)` function that takes a dummy vendor object created in main and produces a pointer (using new) that points to a vendor object which then is passed to the bst and hash table's `add` functions.

Within the bst and hash table, they use new to create a node that contains a pointer to a vendor object and the requisite linking pointers (next, left, right, etc.)

In summary a dummy data object goes to `aCollection::add(aVendor& vendor)`, and a pointer to `aVendor` object (with the data inside it) is sent to the bst and hash table which then store that pointer in their own `node` objects they declared using `new`.

**My question is, how should I use `delete` to properly release the memory?** The bst and hash table share the pointers to the `aVendor` object that was passed to them and they each have their own nodes to delete. **I know I need to call `delete` in the bst and hash table's `remove` functions (to delete their respective nodes)** but how do I ensure that `aVendor` that is created in `aCollection` is deleted once and only once?

P.S. Is calling new in `aCollection` even necessary?  I figure the pointer needs to stay allocated so the data always exists.

The code is a bit verbose so I made a quick illustration of what is going on.
[image: Illustration of program add function]

**----Solution----**

Thanks to Ped7g's excellent explanation I figured out that since `aCollection` should be the function deleting the pointers I needed to keep track of the pointers to be deleted. Going by his/her suggestion I decided to use a `std::list` to add all the pointers added to the program to a list, then I designed a while loop in the destructor that iterates through those pointers and `delete`s them, thus preventing memory leaks stemming from `aCollection`, here is the code I wrote to do so.

```
 20 //Constructor function
 21
 22 aCollection::aCollection()
 23 {
 24     //allocates one instance of a hash table and bst
 25     hashTable = new hashFunctions;
 26     bst = new aBst;
 27
 28     //Creates a list to track ptrs
 29     trackList = std::list<aVendor*>();
 30     return;
 31 }
 32
 33 //Destructor
 34 aCollection::~aCollection()
 35 {
 36     //Destroys hashTable and bst
 37     delete hashTable;
 38     delete bst;
 39     //Deletes vendor pointer objects
 40     while(!trackList.empty())
 41     {
 42         delete trackList.front();
 43         trackList.pop_front();
 44     }
 45     return;
 46 }
```

In the add function I used this line of code to add the pointers to the list

```
 84     trackList.push_front(vendorPtr);
```

And finally this is how I declared the list as part of `aCollection.h`

```
 43     list<aVendor*> trackList;
```

Comment: Use `unique_ptr`, forget that `new` and `delete` exist and everything will work itself out.

Comment: @nwp could you give me an example of how I could use that in this context (perhaps in aCollection)? I read that unique_ptr can't be copied but I have to store a pointer to the object inside both functions.

Comment: @LegionDaeth: Assuming that both collections are complete, it doesn't matter: store the `unique_ptr<Vendor>` in either. If one is a subset of the other, store the `unique_ptr` in the superset.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `aBst` nodes should be std::unique_ptr<treeNode>'s, and the hashtable might be better implemented as `std::unordered_map<Vendor, YourHash>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow the "everything belongs somewhere" principle.

Only the owner of information handles `new`/`delete` (better to say "avoids new/delete as much as possible"), other subjects don't care, if they receive a pointer, they assume it's live trough the whole time of their processing - because that's the owner responsibility, if it gave the pointer away, it should be aware how [long] it will be used outside, and adjust it's strategy of new/delete to fulfil those needs. So they don't delete it.

In your case it depends a lot, whether you remove vendors often from the structure, or you only add vendors to it. If you remove vendors only absolutely rarely and huge performance penalty is allowed then, you can have `std::vector<aVendor> vendors;` (1) in aCollection, giving the bs and hash nodes only iterator (or pointer/index) to the vendor. In case vendor is removed from vector, all bs/hash nodes have to updated with fresh iterator (pointer/index) = performance penalty upon remove. Well, actually inserting vendors will invalidate iterators and pointers too, only indices would survive, so use indices then - which also makes quite clear, how bs/hash nodes care about `delete` of vendor (you don't delete index, makes no sense).

If you remove vendors often, a `std::list` is better choice, as inserting/removing does not invalidate iterators, so all the copies of iterators in bs/hash nodes will remain correct.

Overall it looks like you wrote your own implementation of `std::*` containers... any particular reason for that? (it's a good learning exercise, and in very rare cases the performance decision, but in such case you would end with completely different design, because what you have is as horrible as `std::list` performance wise ... otherwise in production code it's usually much more efficient to stick with standard containers and design implementation around them, as they have reasonably OK-ish performance, and you don't have to implement them, only use).

(1) avoids new/delete completely. If that way is not practical for you (aVendor default constructor is costly), use `std::vector<aVendor *> vendors;` with manual `new`/`delete` upon insert/removal of vendor.

---

edit:

*"how do I ensure that aVendor that is created in aCollection is deleted once and only once?"*

Well, you delete it just once, in `aCollection`.

It's not clear from the question, what is your problem (maybe you are struggling with detection when a vendor is deleted in all nodes, and you want to release it from `aCollection` then too? That's completely different question, and would require much more architecture insight into the app algorithm, to see if there's some good place to detect "dangling" vendor no more used by any node, triggering delete in `aCollection`).

---

edit: how to new/delete example:

[live example](http://cpp.sh/6j6a)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

class Vendor {
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    Vendor(const std::string & name) : name(name) {}
    const std::string & getName() const { return name; }
};

// A bit pointless example how to handle naked new/delete.
class VendorList {
private:
    std::list<Vendor *> vendors;

    // usually with neatly designed classes the std::list<Vendor>
    // would suffice, saving all the hassle with new/delete
    // (that's why this example is a bit pointless)

    // Also storing around iterators to internal list outside
    // of VendorList class feels quite wrong, that's a code smell.

public:
    ~VendorList() {
        std::cout << "~VendorList() destructor called.\n";
        // release any remaining vendors from heap
        auto vendorIterator = vendors.begin();
        while (vendorIterator != vendors.end()) {
            auto toRemove = vendorIterator++;
            removeVendor(toRemove);
        }
        // release the (now invalid) pointers
        vendors.clear();
        // at this point, whoever still holds iterator
        // to a vendor has a problem, it's invalid now.
    }

    // stores vendor into collection of vendors
    // + data of vendor are allocated on heap by "new"
    // returns iterator pointing to the newly added vendor
    // (not a best choice for public API)
    std::list<Vendor *>::iterator addVendor(const Vendor & vendor) {
        Vendor * copyOnHeap = new Vendor(vendor);
        std::cout << "VendorList: adding vendor: "
            << copyOnHeap->getName() << std::endl;
        return vendors.insert(vendors.end(), copyOnHeap);
    }

    // removes particular vendor from the list
    // to be used after the rest of application does not hold any iterator
    void removeVendor(std::list<Vendor *>::iterator vendor_iterator) {
        std::cout << "VendorList: releasing specific vendor: " <<
            (*vendor_iterator)->getName() << std::endl;
        // release the heap memory containing vendor's data
        delete *vendor_iterator;
        // remove the released pointer from list
        vendors.erase(vendor_iterator);
        // at this point, whoever still holds iterator
        // to that vendor has a problem, it's invalid now.
    }

    const std::list<Vendor *> & get() const {
        return vendors;
    }

};

int main()
{
    VendorList vlist;
    vlist.addVendor(Vendor("v1"));
    auto v2iterator = vlist.addVendor(Vendor("v2"));
    vlist.removeVendor(v2iterator);
    for (auto vendorPtr : vlist.get()) {
        std::cout << "Vendor in list: " << vendorPtr->getName() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm not really happy about this example, as it feels wrong on many levels (like bad OOP design), but to make the API fit your purpose, the purpose would have to be known first.

So take this only as an example where `new` and `delete` belongs. (only once in `VendorList`, which is owner + responsible for managing these. Nobody else in app should use `new`/`delete` on Vendor, they should instead call the `VendorList` add/remove functions, and let the list to manage the implementation details (like where it is stored, and how many new/deletes are per vendor used).

Usually by designing your data classes lean, and avoiding naked pointers, you can avoid new/delete completely in C++ code. You can try to turn this example into `std::list<Vendor>` variant, the code will be simplified a lot (empty destructor code, as default would release the list), removal/insert only called on the list, etc.

You then handle the life cycle of data in memory by scope. Like in `main` you have `VendorList vl;`, as that instance of vendor list will be used trough whole life cycle of application. Or if you need it only during invoice processing, you can declare it inside `processInvoices()`, again as local variable, init it, and then forget about it. It will get released when you go out of scope of `processInvoices()`.

Which will release all initialised Vendors, as they belong into VendorList. Etc..

So as long as you manage to design your classes with clear "belongs to" and "responsible for", you can get to a great lengths by using only local/member variables, not using new/delete/shared_ptr/etc... at all. The source will look almost like Java with GC, just shorter and faster, and you implicitly know when the release of particular data happens (when they go out of their scope).

Comment: I treat the `aCollection` as "VendorList" container, which is maybe wrong assumption, but hard to tell from the limited question view. If `aCollection` is generic container class, then the name is ok, otherwise you should rename it to better describe what is it's status and responsibility.

Comment: If new is used to return a pointer to a vendor object and then that pointer is stored in another object, I dont know how to release the vendor object pointer stored in that object. i.e. what was made in collection.

Also I don't seem to be implementing delete correctly in either of the remove functions, but that's off topic.

Comment: @LegionDaeth the pointer is a number, an index into memory. When you give it to somebody else, you are doing a copy of the number... like you have `501` and you give copy of `501` to somebody else. If you forget `501` now, you can't `delete` it anymore, but somebody else can, as long he knows the `501`, and as he knows he should delete it. But if you do both `delete 501;`, that's bug. So best solution is usually to keep new/delete responsibility at the same place, giving the copy of pointer only for temporary usage reasons, but not giving away responsibility of delete itself.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. So I implemented a std::list to keep track of all the vendorPtrs that are sent out to the functions and in the destructor I iterate through it and delete all the pointers so I've completely fixed the memory leak in aCollection using your std:list suggestion. Thanks for the very detailed explanation, I still have bugs in the bst's remove function but i will try and solve that or put it in another topic. Thanks!